# Android graphs: get x axis label on bar chart click

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'm using Chart engine for drawing graphs in my app. Graphs are displaying good, but in onClick of bar chart i need to display the CLICKED bar X AXIS label as toast. so How can i retrieve x axis label?
i've tried

```
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
```

but here there's nothing related to x axis label..

Comment: Do you need the X axis custom label (the one you may have set using renderer.addXTextLabel()) or the default numerical value?

Comment: @Dan: yes, I need the X axis TEXT LABEL. how can i get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your piece of code where you obtained a `SeriesSelection` object, you can then get the closest X axis value using:

```
double x = seriesSelection.getXValue();
```

and then in order to get the custom label you can do:

```
String label = renderer.getXTextLabel(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer here [How do I draw a graph on Android without using any external API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897582/how-do-i-draw-a-graph-on-android-without-using-any-external-api/11900610#11900610)

Comment: i'm just a beginner i cant understand a thing in that! and its not using achartengine also!!

Comment: @Jarvis:this chart is using without an api..You can draw bar or line chart by given X and Y axis

Comment: I've already done lot of customizations using chart engine in my graphs, now again i cant start from starting..

Comment: The questions is: how to do something with AChartEngine, not what should I use for charting.